# Download file on server through script

Tags: php, file, download, header, attachment

If I have a page with url `download.php?id=312`, which downloads a file from the server, can I somehow find out the absolute path to the file on the server? The filename is 'hidden' since it's downloaded through the file `download.php` but can the file give a clue where the file was downloaded from or is it completely hidden?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not find that out. That file, might be even generated on the fly, upon http request to url with parameter `download.php?id=312` as a response

Comment: But it's an uploaded pdf file, so the file has to be stored somewhere. I just thought I could use Chrome's developer tool or something else to check sources etc.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php .. try this on youl local machine .. to the meta of that file

Comment: images many times store even geolocation data, where image was taken, exposure time, focal length.. etc .. Iphone in photos store ridiqulous amount of meta.